# shell formatting broken under macos Terminal resize (Ubuntu 18.04 / bash 4.4.20)

Tags: bash, ubuntu

I just upgraded a server from Ubuntu 14.04.4 to 18.04.5, and with it my bash shell was upgraded from 4.3.11 to 4.4.20. I'm connecting to the server using ssh within the Terminal app under macOS 10.15.7.

If I have a long prompt visible, e.g.:

```
servername:/some/long/path/that/fits/on/one/line/when/the/window/is/wide$
```

and then I shrink the macOS Terminal window, it ends up looking like:

```
when/the/window/is/wide$ servername:/some/long/path/that/fits/o
```

and generally leaves a lot of stray characters all over the place as I resize the Terminal window.

On the old server this worked fine, and I think the only changes are the Ubuntu upgrade which brought a new bash version with it. I tried to find other reports of this problem and I'm sure they're out there, but it was a tricky thing to google for. Can anyone point me toward a resource that might help? I'm unclear if it's macOS or Terminal or Ubuntu or bash (or some other piece of software I've taken for granted in my Ubuntu distribution!).

Answer (score 1):

I figured this out and it was rather particular to my setup, but I'll post the answer here in case it helps someone in the future.

I had edited ~/.bashrc to customize my prompt, and I omitted a `\[` (this begins a sequence of non-printable characters). I guess all bets are off if your prompt has imbalanced brackets in it!